# How to make progress indicator responsive

Tags: responsive-design, sapui5, nsprogressindicator

I have made 3 Progress Indicators in horizontal layout with reference to [Sample - Progress Indicator](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.ProgressIndicator/sample/sap.m.sample.ProgressIndicator)
(which is done in vertical layout) as below:

```
<l:HorizontalLayout
        class="sapUiContentPadding"
        width="100%">
        <l:content>
            <ProgressIndicator
                class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom"
                percentValue="30"
                displayValue="30%"
                showValue="true"
                width="28.7rem"
                state="None" />
            <ProgressIndicator
                class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom"
                percentValue="50"
                showValue="false"
                width="28.7rem"
                state="Error" />
            <ProgressIndicator
                class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom"
                percentValue="99"
                displayValue="0.99GB of 1GB"
                showValue="true"
                width="28.7rem"
                state="Success" />
        </l:content>
    </l:HorizontalLayout>
```

To fit the screen with equal size of 3 indicators I used `width="28.7rem"` but this may be not the correct way to do so and not responsive either(known)

### Image of result:

[image: 3 progress indicators in same line]

To make it responsive, I have read that I should wrap the whole thing in flex box so I tried as:

```
<l:content>
         <Panel class="sapUiDemoFlexBoxSizeAdjustments">
            <FlexBox
                alignItems="Start">
                    <items>
            <ProgressIndicator
                class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom"
                percentValue="30"
                displayValue="30%"
                showValue="true"
                width="100%"
                state="None" />
            <ProgressIndicator
                class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom"
                percentValue="50"
                showValue="false"
                width="100%"
                state="Error" />
            <ProgressIndicator
                class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom"
                percentValue="99"
                displayValue="0.99GB of 1GB"
                showValue="true"
                width="100%"
                state="Success" />
                    </items>
            </FlexBox>
          </Panel>
        </l:content>
    </l:HorizontalLayout>
```

But this didn't help me either (I guess my code is wrong).

May I know how can I achieve these responsive progress indicators?

Comment: As per your requirement for large size devices you need 3 indicators. What about the other size devices like medium and small size devices? You are concentration only for large size devices?

Comment: sorry for not mentioning, I am looking for medium and small devices also...is it possible to show 2 in a row and 1 in next row for these devices, or 3 in one row would be much better

Comment: You cound use layoutData to display them on one row for XL(arge) and L(arge) screen, spread across 2 rows on M(edium) screens and one per row for S(mall) screens

Comment: @Lumpenstein How could I use the layoutData with `<ProgressIndicator` ?....this is simple for `button's` as docs provided some example!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per you requirement you can use the GRID layout to achieve it.

```
<l:Grid containerQuery="true" defaultSpan="XL2 L4" class="gridProgressIndicator ">
    <ProgressIndicator
        class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom"
        percentValue="30"
        displayValue="30%"
        showValue="true"
        state="None" />
     <ProgressIndicator
        class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom"
        percentValue="50"
        showValue="false"
        state="Error" />
     <ProgressIndicator
        class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom"
        percentValue="99"
        displayValue="0.99GB of 1GB"
        showValue="true"
        state="Success" />
</l:Grid>
```

Note: Grid layout will provide the responsive layout. Where `containerQuery` is used to get the size based on the Grid size not based on the device sizes(Large, Medium and Small).
`defaultSpan` is set based on your requirement. For more information regarding the Grid go through the [Grid API](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.Grid)

**Style**

```
/* Progress indicator styling */    
.gridProgressIndicator .sapMPIBarRemaining {
    border-top-right-radius: 1.5rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1.5rem;
}
.gridProgressIndicator .sapMPI, 
.gridProgressIndicator .sapUiSizeCompact .sapMPI:not(.sapMPIDisplayOnly) {
    height: 2rem;
    border-radius: 22px;
}
```

**Output**

**Large Device**

[image]

**Medium Device**

[image]

**Small Device**

[image]

URLs can be relative or full.

Comment: TYSM , May I know bit of explaination sir?.....1)why choose grid 2) why `containerQuery` is set to true and 3) How to set defaultSpan ?.....would learn from them

Comment: also may I know about properties that are used to increase height of each indicator and also to style the display value?

Comment: I am indeed looking for some help to increase the height of indicator and also aligning the text(displayValue) inside it in middle,making bold

Comment: I have updated the answer, kindly check it out. Yes you can increase the indicator height and change the display value as well.

Comment: referred docs and I am able to change the height using `height` property (height: ** rem) but how about the display value mate?

Comment: I have updated the code, which included a  new style class `gridProgressIndicator` to the Grid layout and CSS to increase the height and border alignment.

Comment: so similarly now I can align text in middle as text-align: middle in css (getting id by inspecting elements)?

Comment: Yes you can use the `text-align: center` to make the text at center.

Comment: Does that gap between indicators can be reduced or removed ? and also text at center.